# What do these Firebase Google Cloud Function `DEBUG` severity logs mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been using Logs Explorer to inspect my Firebase Google Cloud Function.

The cloud function works as expected, so I was surprised to find various `DEBUG` severity logs in Logs Explorer.

Also when looking at those logs there isn't any clear information for the cause or problem.

So why am I seeing these `DEBUG` severity logs and what do they mean?

Here is a screenshot of the `DEBUG` logs in Logs Explorer:

[image]

And here are the payloads of each `DEBUG` log:

**DEBUG log 1:**

```JSON
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution started",
  "insertId": "000000-8ce5e770-7b77-4a3b-b117-d1da870c625c",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "agentcake-app-75f12",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "getZohoDeskTicketsLoggedInUser"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:43.908875861Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "algpjnkt4jk5"
  },
  "logName": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/traces/499b082c83a571995237fe47e65243d1",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:54.727147697Z"
}
```

**DEBUG log 2:**

```JSON
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution took 39 ms, finished with status code: 204",
  "insertId": "000000-8f0e70dd-10c4-4d0a-a319-f73ce04f4f33",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "agentcake-app-75f12",
      "function_name": "getZohoDeskTicketsLoggedInUser",
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:43.947441971Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "algpjnkt4jk5"
  },
  "logName": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/traces/499b082c83a571995237fe47e65243d1",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:54.727147697Z"
}
```

**DEBUG log 3:**

```JSON
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution started",
  "insertId": "000000-1252ca30-6f7a-477f-9845-ed1c06ad9d25",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "getZohoDeskTicketsLoggedInUser",
      "project_id": "agentcake-app-75f12"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:44.313316115Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "algpnb41b69d"
  },
  "logName": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/traces/a78c37916b173ecac071ee290da7d968",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:54.727147697Z"
}
```

**DEBUG log 4:**

```JSON
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution took 3141 ms, finished with status code: 200",
  "insertId": "000000-da00728a-e2f2-45f3-a4f2-3b17a4c2ada8",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "getZohoDeskTicketsLoggedInUser",
      "project_id": "agentcake-app-75f12"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:47.454109349Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "algpnb41b69d"
  },
  "logName": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/agentcake-app-75f12/traces/a78c37916b173ecac071ee290da7d968",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-01T07:22:54.727147697Z"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_runtime_logs),

> Internal system messages have the DEBUG log level.

Comment: Thanks for digging that one out for me. Seems strange to have these simple system messages classed as DEBUG when they also have another INFO severity they use for everything else. The DEBUG severity makes it seem like something is wrong or needs attention, when in fact it does not.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_runtime_logs), the `DEBUG` log levels in the Cloud Functions log are just the internal system messages i.e. when your execution started, the status of the function execution, the time taken for function execution etc it is recorded as `DEBUG` log level. So even if your Cloud Functions does not have any error and works fine, it will have the `DEBUG` logs.